# satisfaction of a sentence with two quantifiers

Tags: proof-verification, model-theory, first-order-logic

I want to be sure that I understand how to show that a structure satisfies a sentence under a variable assignment, and suspect that I'm handling the computation of multiple quantifiers incorrectly.  Consider the structure,

(1) $M = \langle \{a\}, \emptyset \rangle$  (i.e., the structure whose domain contains only $a$ and whose "membership" relation is just the empty set)

and the sentence,

(2) $\exists y \forall x (x \not \in y)$  (i.e., the Empty Set Axiom)

Now, (1) is evidently a model of (2).  But is the following argument mistaken (where $a$ is any variable assignment, and $a~ (x/b)$ is the variable assignment just like $a$ but which maps $x$ to $b$)?

$$\langle \{a\},~ \emptyset \rangle \models \exists y \forall x (x \not \in y)~[a]$$

If and only if for some $b \in \{a\}$:

$$\langle \{a\},~ \emptyset \rangle \models \forall x (x \not \in y)~[a~(y/b)]$$

If and only if for some $b \in \{a\}$ and for all $c \in \{a\}$:

$$\langle \{a\},~ \emptyset \rangle \models (x \not \in y)~[a~(y/b)~(x/c)]$$

If and only if for some $b \in \{a\}$ and for all $c \in \{a\}$:

$$\lnot\bigg(\langle \{a\},~ \emptyset \rangle \models (x \not \in y)~[a~(y/b)~(x/c)]\bigg)$$

which is true, since all $c \in \{a\}$ are equal to $a$, and $a$ is not in $\emptyset$.

Comment: You are interpreting the formula in a structure $M$ with *domain* $\{ a \}$.  Thus, if $a$ is the only object in the domain, "some $b$" must be $a$... And if the "membership" relation is just the empty set, then $a$ has no elements. Thus, $(x \notin a)$ is true for every $c \in \{ a \}$, i.e. for $a$. because the "couple" $⟨a,a⟩$ is not in the "empty" membership relation.

Comment: Thanks!  That's what I thought I wrote near the end.  Did I mess something up?

Comment: Exactly; the "variants" of the variable assignment $a$ are not variant at all, because there is only one element in the domain (i.e. $a$) to be assigned to $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Actually, I guess the very last clause should say "and <a, a> is not in 0."